# How to omit `find ` failed items in macOS?

Tags: terminal

When I use `$ find / -name mywork-process`, it will display the `No such file or directory` and `Permission denied`, there are too many items, I can not distinguish.

```
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PKInstallSandboxManager: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/boot: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/Apple/Screen Sharing/Keys: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/Apple/ParentalControls/Users: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/Apple/AssetCache/Data: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/Apple/Remote Desktop/Task Server: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/Apple/Remote Desktop/Client: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/ApplePushService: Permission denied
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
...
```

is there any way to ignore those ones?

Comment: Just add `2>/dev/null` at the end of your `find` _command_ and you'll not see that _output_.

Comment: Why do you need to search with find from the root?

Comment: @MarcWilson if I install a software, it may be `/usr/local/`  maybe `/opt`, and other place under `/`, do you think the is any other way to avoid search `/`?

Comment: Well, if you installed something, you should know where you installed it, why are you having to search for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a function that can filter out the lines you want omitted. I would suggest the function shown below.

```
filter() { grep -v -e "No such file or directory" -e "Permission denied" -e "Operation not permitted"; }
```

Second, use the filter as shown below.

```
find / -name mywork-process 2> >(filter)
```

***Suggestion:*** To help prevent searching other mounted volumes, use the `-x` option, as shown below.

```
find -x / -name mywork-process 2> >(filter)
```